# Generating function related to ${2n}\choose{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, random-walk

We have:
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x} =\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}x^n $$
This is a well-known result about the generating function of Catalan numbers.
Now, I'm curious and really eager to know if we have such closed form for
$$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}^2x^n$$
**Question**: After some attempts, I failed all so I wonder if is there really a closed form? 

**A bit of context** :So why this question may bear some interesting things? Because, this is a natural thing we may come up if we calculate the the expectation of number of times a two dimensional random walk returning to 0. That is, let $(S_n)$ be a simple symmetric random walks in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, $L_N = \sum_{k=0}^N \mathbb{1}_{S_k=(0,0)}$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}(L_{2N})=\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{1}{16^n}$$

**Remark**: $\mathbb{E}(L_{2N})= \Theta(\log N)$

Comment: According to Wolfram Mathematica, this sum equals $\frac{2}{\pi}K(16x)$ where $K$ denotes the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. So it is unlikely that there exists a nice closed form for this series.

Comment: (+1) Thank you. Follow up question, I don't know how to use Wolfram to find the the closed of power series. Can you show me how?

Comment: A link is here : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5B2*n%2C+n%5D%5E2*x%5En%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D (for some reasons it only yields the partial sums so one has to take the limit)

Comment: @Evariste : Nice! Thank you.

Comment: @Evariste is correct except that $16t$ should be $\sqrt{16t}$ if you use the standard notation used throughout the mathematics literature for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. Wolfram’s implementation of the function deviates from this convention, I have no idea why, which is why it reports the evaluation the way it does. Anyway, Wikipedia should give you plenty of references on this function, which is considered just as “closed-form” as any other standard math function.

Comment: @DanRomik (+1) Thank you for your remark.